# if else condition with radio button not working on button click in android

Tags: android, if-statement, radio-button

I am stuck in simple code. I am trying to check which `Radiobutton` is checked and then showing results on `Button` click. When i click Male Radio Button, it shows results perfectly But when i check female radio button then its showing nothing or you can say its not working and even not showing any error. I don't know whats wrong with my code. Please take a look:

```
RadioButton radm,radf;
radm=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiomale);
radf=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiofemale);
Button find=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnfind);

//Where s is Spinner and find is Button

   find.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

if(s.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("KG")){

                    if(radm.isChecked()){


                        int inches= myfoot*12+myinch;

                        float sizeincm= inches*2.54f;
                        mybmr= (float) (66.47f+ (13.7*myweight) +(5*sizeincm) -6.8 * myage);
                        myrmr= (float) ((10*myweight)+(6.25*sizeincm)-(5*myage)+5);
                        mygcal=level.getSelectedItem().toString();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Output_activity.class);
                        Bundle extras = new Bundle();

                        extras.putFloat("bmr",mybmr);
                        extras.putFloat("rmr",myrmr);
                        extras.putString("gcal",mygcal);
                        intent.putExtras(extras);
                        startActivity(intent);


                    }
                }



                   else if(s.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("KG")){
                   if(radf.isChecked()) {

                            int inches = myfoot * 12 + myinch;

                            float sizeincm = inches * 2.54f;
                            mybmr = (float) (655.1f + (9.6 * myweight) + (1.8 * sizeincm) - 4.7 * myage);
                            myrmr = (float) ((10 * myweight) + (6.25 * sizeincm) - (5 * myage) + 5);
                            mygcal = level.getSelectedItem().toString();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Output_activity.class);
                            Bundle extras = new Bundle();

                            extras.putFloat("bmr", mybmr);
                            extras.putFloat("rmr", myrmr);
                            extras.putString("gcal", mygcal);
                            intent.putExtras(extras);
                            startActivity(intent);


                        }
                }
     }
    });
```

Here is my XML:

```
  <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radmf"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:text="Male"
            android:checked="true"
            android:background="@drawable/customedittext"
            android:id="@+id/radiomale"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>


        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:text="Female"
            android:background="@drawable/customedittext"
            android:id="@+id/radiofemale"/>


    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Try debug and see what value you get

Comment: I tried, But Its not going on second if else, I Mean at female radio button.

Comment: In your Else if you are doing same check as you did in your if statement. Put Content from Else if in your if.

Comment: Anders i am doing same check for spinner but changing my radio button male to female. I also tried if( !radm.ischecked) in second condition. I also removed   if(radf.isChecked()) in second if else. But seriously dont know what the hell is going on.. Its really simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved my Problem Like this:

```
  if(s.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("KG") && radm.isChecked()){




                        int inches= myfoot*12+myinch;

                        float sizeincm= inches*2.54f;
                        mybmr= (float) (66.47f+ (13.7*myweight) +(5*sizeincm) -6.8 * myage);
                        myrmr= (float) ((10*myweight)+(6.25*sizeincm)-(5*myage)+5);
                        mygcal=level.getSelectedItem().toString();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Output_activity.class);
                        Bundle extras = new Bundle();

                        extras.putFloat("bmr",mybmr);
                        extras.putFloat("rmr",myrmr);
                        extras.putString("gcal",mygcal);
                        intent.putExtras(extras);
                        startActivity(intent);


                }



                  else if(s.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("KG") && radf.isChecked()){



                            int inches = myfoot * 12 + myinch;

                            float sizeincm = inches * 2.54f;
                            mybmr = (float) (655.1f + (9.6 * myweight) + (1.8 * sizeincm) - 4.7 * myage);
                            myrmr = (float) ((10 * myweight) + (6.25 * sizeincm) - (5 * myage) + 5);
                            mygcal = level.getSelectedItem().toString();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Output_activity.class);
                            Bundle extras = new Bundle();

                            extras.putFloat("bmr", mybmr);
                            extras.putFloat("rmr", myrmr);
                            extras.putString("gcal", mygcal);
                            intent.putExtras(extras);
                            startActivity(intent);



                }
```

Still thankful to Anders for your time. Thanks

Comment: np, glad you fixed it

Comment: :) stay blessed

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
RadioButton radm,radf;
radm=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiomale);
radf=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiofemale);
Button find=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnfind);

//Where s is Spinner and find is Button

find.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(s.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("KG")){

            if(radm.isChecked()){
                int inches= myfoot*12+myinch;

                float sizeincm= inches*2.54f;
                mybmr= (float) (66.47f+ (13.7*myweight) +(5*sizeincm) -6.8 * myage);
                myrmr= (float) ((10*myweight)+(6.25*sizeincm)-(5*myage)+5);
                mygcal=level.getSelectedItem().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Output_activity.class);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();

                extras.putFloat("bmr",mybmr);
                extras.putFloat("rmr",myrmr);
                extras.putString("gcal",mygcal);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(intent);


            }else if (radf.isChecked()){
                    int inches = myfoot * 12 + myinch;

                    float sizeincm = inches * 2.54f;
                    mybmr = (float) (655.1f + (9.6 * myweight) + (1.8 * sizeincm) - 4.7 * myage);
                    myrmr = (float) ((10 * myweight) + (6.25 * sizeincm) - (5 * myage) + 5);
                    mygcal = level.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Output_activity.class);
                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();

                    extras.putFloat("bmr", mybmr);
                    extras.putFloat("rmr", myrmr);
                    extras.putString("gcal", mygcal);
                    intent.putExtras(extras);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Let me try Anders!

Comment: No.. I also tried this before you answerd.. But this is not working!